# Slick Slider Vertical Center Slide Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I am using center mode in the vertical slider of a slick slider in my project. The demo on their website is always active in the center slide and they have 3 slides in total. But in my case, I have 9 slides and when I apply their setting and make the slides 9, it again actives the second one but I need it to active the center which will e 5th slide. 
I am attaching my project screenshot and my code

Javascript Code

```
$('.slider-for').slick(
{
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    arrows: false,
    fade: false,
    adaptiveHeight: true,
    infinite: false,
    useTransform: true,
    speed: 400,
});

$('.slider-nav').slick(
{
    slidesToShow: 9,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    asNavFor: '.slider-for',
    dots: false,
    arrows: false,
    centerMode: true,
    focusOnSelect: true,
    vertical: true
});
```

[image: Project Image]

Answer (score 0):

On there site, In center mode they have six slides but showing 3 slides at a time and scrolling 1 slide per click.
Therfore, ***slideToShow *** must be the value how many slide you want to show in their case it's 3. not how many slide you have.

I think, you can try putting 
slideToShow: 3

Comment: Numbers of slide are 9 i want to center slide number 5.

Comment: when make i  *slideToShow * 3 it make the slider like this image is in the link ( https://prnt.sc/r2o45z ).

Comment: you can put initialSlide: 4 or 5 from where you want to start. And in your case you may be want to put 9 slides then you can put slideToShow : 9